# Using VB.net how would I implement DataGridView to display contents of the 2 dimensional array in the form?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, display

This program reads an excel file into a 2 dimensional array. Now I need to display the results in a grid like view the same as the original excel file. I was told DataGridView might be able to help. Not sure how to proceed.

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
```

Create new Application.

```
    Dim excel As Application = New Application
```

Open Excel spreadsheet.

```
    Dim w As Workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open("G:\PACE\New Style Project\01.xls")
```

Loop over all sheets.

```
    For i As Integer = 1 To w.Sheets.Count
```

Get sheet.

```
        Dim sheet As Worksheet = w.Sheets(i)
```

Get range.

```
        Dim r As Range = sheet.UsedRange

Load all cells into 2d array.
        Dim array(,) As Object = r.Value(XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault)
```

Scan the cells.

```
        If array IsNot Nothing Then
            'Console.WriteLine("Length: {0}", Array.Length)
```

Get bounds of the array.

```
            Dim bound0 As Integer = Array.GetUpperBound(0)
            Dim bound1 As Integer = Array.GetUpperBound(1)

            'Console.WriteLine("Dimension 0: {0}", bound0)
            'Console.WriteLine("Dimension 1: {0}", bound1)
```

Loop over all elements.

```
            For j As Integer = 1 To bound0
                For x As Integer = 1 To bound1
                    Dim s1 As String = Array(j, x)
                    'Console.Write(s1)
                    'Console.Write(" "c)


                Next
                'Console.WriteLine()

            Next
        End If
    Next

    ' Close.
    w.Close()
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and easy way to achieve this is to use Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0.....

here is a simple example....

```
    Dim DataSet As New DataSet
    Try
        Dim con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + "<Path to your Excel file>" + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")

        con.Open()
        Dim atatable = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing)

        Dim sql As String

        Dim excelcomm = New OleDbCommand()
        Dim adexcel = New OleDbDataAdapter(excelcomm)

        Dim tableInfo = con.GetSchema("Tables")
        For Each row As DataRow In tableInfo.Rows
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", row("TABLE_NAME").ToString)
            Dim sheetname = row("TABLE_NAME").ToString

            sql = "select * from [" + sheetname + "]"
            adexcel.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
            adexcel.Fill(DataSet, sheetname)
        Next


    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    DataGridView1.DataSource = DataSet.Tables(0) ' set DataGridView1 to display first table
```

Try the code first, if you get an error

```
the 'microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine
```

at 'con.Open()' then you might need to install the AccessDatabaseEngine.exe (32 bit version not the 64 bit version) from here

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255